# Expected Identifier When Using Anonymous Function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, anonymous-function

I have a GridView that has a structure like this:

- group-header

  - dept-header

    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)
  - dept-header

    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)
- group-header

  - dept-header

    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)
  - dept-header

    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)

While I have Javascript that toggles the dept-header and sub-elements that works as intended, toggle does not work at group header level because the sub elements of one dept-header could be toggled, but not another dept-header so when toggle is activated at the group-header level it just inverts the toggling which is not what I want so I tried to write some Javascript that when group-header is clicked it would just hide all the concurrent rows regardless of toggle state until the next group-header if they weren't hidden, else clicking the group-header would show/expand the hidden rows regardless of toggle state until the next group-header.

Due to being new to Javascript I am currently running across an `'Expected identifier'` at the paren just left of the anon function at the end and can't determine the cause as it looks like I have closure, but I suspect I'm using incorrect syntax for an anon func and my function may be written incorrectly anyways:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.group-header').click(function () {
            $(this).nextUntil('.group-header').(function() {
                var el = document.getElementById(this);
                if (el.style.display != 'none') {
                    el.style.display = 'none';
                }
                else {
                    el.style.display = '';
                }
            })
        });
    });

    $(function () {
        $('.dept-header').click(function () {
            $(this).nextUntil('.dept-header, .group-header').toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

How do I fix what is wrong with the error I'm getting?

Comment: `r').(function() {` syntax error there. Did you forget the each?

Comment: Ah yes, each seems to fix that error. Now getting JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference at `if (el.style.display != 'none') {` which I'll have to figure out what obj I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is you have a random () in your code. Thinking you missed `each`

```
$(this).nextUntil('.group-header').(function() {
                                 ^^^^
```

Next issue is you can not use `this` with getElementById.

```
var el = document.getElementById(this);
```

Should just be

```
var el = this;
```

Comment: Even after changing to `var el = this;` getting JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'display' of undefined or null reference at `if (el.style.display != 'none')`

Comment: Well what is `el`? `console.log(el);`

Comment: Using VS breakpoint, `el` has Type [Object, Window] with Value {...}

Comment: and you added the missing else? `.else(function(){})`

Comment: I added the missing each so it now looks like:
    `$(function () {
        $('.group-header').click(function () {
            $(this).nextUntil('.group-header').each(function () {
                var el = this;
                if (el.style.display != 'none') {
                    el.style.display = 'none';
                }
                else {
                    el.style.display = '';
                }
            }())
        });
    });`

Comment: I'm going to create another question just to separate out the syntax issue you solved and this issue. Will post link to new question here should you wish to solve.

Comment: Question can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619833/how-to-hide-show-gridview-rows