# How to Hide && Show GridView rows onclick of header element with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, gridview, show-hide

I have a GridView that has a structure like this:

- group-header

  - dept-header

    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)
  - dept-header

    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)
- group-header

  - dept-header

    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)
  - dept-header

    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)

While I have Javascript that toggles the dept-header and sub-elements that works as intended, toggle does not work at group header level because the sub elements of one dept-header could be toggled, but not another dept-header so when toggle is activated at the group-header level it just inverts the toggling which is not what I want so I tried to write some Javascript that when group-header is clicked it would just hide all the concurrent rows regardless of toggle state until the next group-header if they weren't hidden, else clicking the group-header would show/expand the hidden rows regardless of toggle state until the next group-header.

However, I have not been able to work out the code so that when group-header is clicked it hides all the following rows until the next group-header if they aren't hidden, else shows them. Currently I run into a `"JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'display' of undefined or null reference"` at the `if (el.style.display != 'none')` line which suggests that I'm not properly manipulating objects, but I'm not sure what obj's or attr's to manipulate to get the desired effect due to my being new to Javascript.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.group-header').click(function () {
            $(this).nextUntil('.group-header').each(function () {
                var el = this;
                if (el.style.display != 'none') {
                    el.style.display = 'none';
                }
                else {
                    el.style.display = '';
                }
            }())
        });
    });

    $(function () {
        $('.dept-header').click(function () {
            $(this).nextUntil('.dept-header, .group-header').toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

For reference my Razor code:

```
<table id="companyGrid" class="table table-bordered table-striped grid">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Designation)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Department)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Company)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Year)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Salary)
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var group in Model.GroupBy(x => x.Company))
    {
        <tr class="group-header">
            <td colspan="7">
                <span class="h2">@group.Key</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        foreach (var dept in group.GroupBy(x => x.Department))
        {
            <tr class="dept-header">
                <td colspan="6">
                    <span class="h4">@dept.Key</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            foreach (var item in dept)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Designation)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Company)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Salary)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
        <tr class="group-footer">
            <td colspan="6" class="text-center">
                <span class="label label-info">Company: @group.Key</span>
                <span class="label label-success">Total Employee: @group.Count()</span>
                <span class="label label-primary">Avg Salary: @group.Average(x => x.Salary).ToString("C")</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
        $('.group-header').click(function () {
            $(this).children('.dept-header').each(function () {
               $(this).slideToggle();
            })
        });
    });


 $(function () {
        $('.group-header').click(function () {
            $(this).children('.dept-header').each(function () {
                var el = this;
                if (el.style.display != 'none') {
                    el.style.display = 'none';
                }
                else {
                    el.style.display = '';
                }
            })
        });
    });
**UPDATE :** 
 $(function () {
    $('.group-header').click(function () {
        $(this).nextUntil('.group-header').each(function () {
            var el = this;
            if (el.style.display != 'none') {
                el.style.display = 'none';
            }
            else {
                el.style.display = '';
            }
        })
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

```
$(function () {
                      $('.group-header').click(function () {
                          var parentgrpHeader = $(this);

                          $(this).nextUntil('.group-header').each(function () {
                             !parentgrpHeader.hasClass("toggle") ?  $(this).hide() : $(this).show();
                          });

                          parentgrpHeader.toggleClass('toggle');
                      });


                       $('.dept-header').click(function () {
                          $(this).toggleClass('collapsed').nextUntil('.dept-header, .group-header').toggle();
                      });


              });
```

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't quite work for the case I'm trying to do, not sure if it being in td tr would mess with the javascript at all instead of divs. I put the raw HTML that the Razor code generates in this fiddle. All the rows between ABC Infotech and TPS Software should vanish upon clicking ABC Infotech. https://jsfiddle.net/qLhhk3oq/1/

Comment: Actually I just realized this answer suffers the same issue as what I was trying to solve, if the dept-headers are collapsed, then clicking the group-header collapses them such that the data under dept-headers inverts and becomes visible https://jsfiddle.net/qLhhk3oq/3/

Comment: Clicking the group header always expands the dept-headers, it never collapses.

Comment: @KurtWagner : Yes I know but now you should take some steps and fix it for yourself. If you are not able to do so. You can ask again. -Thanks.