# How to Properly Check if First Child is Hidden and Then Set Function Bool

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm trying to come up with an answer to a recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619833/how-to-hide-show-gridview-rows-onclick-of-header-element-with-javascript) of mine and I believe the best answer involves a function peeking at the first child element and then setting a bool outside of that function for another function to use.

To recap:
I have a GridView that has a structure like this:

- group-header

  - dept-header

    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)
  - dept-header

    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)
- group-header

  - dept-header

    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)
  - dept-header

    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)
    - (some person entity)

Basically, I want it so that when group-header is clicked it hides all the following rows until the next group-header if they aren't hidden, else shows them.

I have the code and HTML set up at https://jsfiddle.net/dLp47mtd/1/, but the code in question that is not expanding/collapsing is:

```
// Hide/Show Group's Data on Click
$(function() {
    $('.group-header').click(function() {
        // Assume first dept-header not visible
        var nextVisible = 0;
        // Check if the first dept-header is visible
        $(this).firstChild(function() {
            var el = this;
            // If visible, change our assumption
            if (el.style.display === '') {
                nextVisible = 1;
            }
        });

        // If visible, hide all sub-elements else show all sub-elements
        $(this).nextUntil('.group-header').each(function() {
            var el = this;    
            if (nextVisible === 1) {
                el.style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                el.style.display = '';
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me, provided you want to show and hide all rows under the group without remembering what departments may have been toggled already.

https://jsfiddle.net/dLp47mtd/5/

```
// Hide/Show Dept's Data on Click
$(function () {
    $('.dept-header').click(function () {
        $(this).nextUntil('.dept-header, .group-header').toggle();
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('.group-header').click(function () {
        var elm = $(this);
        if (elm.next().is(":visible")) {
            elm.nextUntil('.group-header').hide();
        } else {
            elm.nextUntil('.group-header').show();
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Cool thanks! I changed some of the code to `elm.nextUntil('.group-header', '.dept-header').show();` so that dept-header was still collapsed when group-header was expanded, but the code you gave provided the great jumping point I needed to further enhance the UI.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dLp47mtd/4/)

```
$('.group-header').click(function() 
{
    $(this).nextAll().each(function()
    {
        if($(this).hasClass("group-header"))
            return false;
        if($(this).is(":visible"))
            $(this).hide();
        else
            $(this).show();
    });
});
```